# Adapter for objects from JSON

Tags: android

I get data in JSON from API, and there are id and url. Now, i need to create a button "Add to favorites" for each image that i display. When i try to set `adapter.setListener(this);`, i get an error, because i can't use string format.

How can i resolve this problem? I spend 5 hours on this, and can't resolve it :(

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listItem);
    favorites = findViewById(R.id.buttonFav);
    catDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this ,catDetailsArrayList);
    searchbtn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);

    searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            catDetailsArrayList.clear();
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            displayCats();
        }
    });


    });


}

private void displayCats() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try{

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String jsonCatUrl2 = jsonObject1.getString("url");
                    String jsonCatId2 = jsonObject1.getString("id");

                    CatDetails catDetails = new CatDetails();

                    catDetails.setUrl(jsonCatUrl2);
                    catDetails.setId(jsonCatId2);

                    catDetailsArrayList.add(catDetails);

                }
                listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


public Activity activity;
public ArrayList<CatDetails> catDetailsArrayList;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

Button btn;
TextView idnr;


public MyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<CatDetails> catDetailsArrayList) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.catDetailsArrayList = catDetailsArrayList;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return catDetailsArrayList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long)position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = this.activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    final CatDetails catDetails = this.catDetailsArrayList.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load(catDetails.getUrl()).into(imageView);
    idnr =convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonFav);
    final String id = catDetails.getId();
    idnr.setText(catDetails.getId());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.catDetailsArrayList.size();
}
```

I display the id that i receive from server for each item, it's ok, but i don't know how to set the button "add to favorites" to works fine. It must receive item id (that i received from server) as a param, but id is in string format.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final String id = catDetails.getId();
```

change it to

```
final String id = Integer.toString(catDetails.getId());
```